# Melee in Star Wars Battlefront II

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

I've just started playing Star Wars Battlefront II, and there are a lot of differences between this game and the 2015 game, especially the melee. In Star Wars Battlefront 2015 the melee did 50 damage and was very slow. In the sequel the melees are much quicker and seem to do much less damage. I was wondering how much damage it does and if it differs by class, for instance it would make sense if assault and heavy do more damage than officer and specialist.

Comment: It probably does less melee damage because there's a Star Card for more melee damage. To keep things "balanced", you know?

Comment: Its not that the melee does less damage than it did before, 50 points. Its that many classes have more than 100 health, so it takes more than 2 to bring them down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've gathered all melee attacks deal a standard amount of damage, unless improved by a star card. I usually run a build that lets me punch people much harder than they are able to hit me.